# Java dynamic binding when using inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, binding, polymorphism

For the following code:

```
class A { 
    public void ex(Object o) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A { 
    public void ex(B o) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public void ex(A o) {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        C xx;
        xx = new C();
        xx.ex(xx); // This prints B
    }
}
```

Why is the result of calling the **ex** method "B"? Both the reference and class type are C, still the method executed is the one from the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the class chain you created C instances will have all 3 methods available:

- A.ex(Object)
- B.ex(B)
- C.ex(A)

All of them could be used for your `xx.ex(xx)` invocation. At this point, according to the Java spec, the most specific method is invoked.

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

As you don't have an `ex(C)` method, the most specific method that matches your invocation is `B.ex(B)` as B is a subclass of A, which is a subclass of Object.